# Git: checkout Repo1 and merge to Repo 2 using custom origin

Tags: git, azure-devops

Here is my scenario and  what i want to achieve with Git (Azure DevOps), please guide.

**Scenario**

- Using an open source project as part of my main project. Call it REPO 1 hosted in GITHub.
- Time to time i have to merge the updates in my main repository REPO 2 (Azure DevOps), and it is obvious both have separate names.
- REPO 2 have some custom code on top of what i get from REPO1 that for few files i have to manually.

**Want to Achieve**

- Checkout REPO 1 - make all my manual change in that.
- Merge it to REPO 2 - Dev branch for that module
- After test REPO 2 Dev branch, will raise PULL to master of REPO 2 branch.

**What i tried till now**

- Checked out REPO 1 with it's only branch that is master, made the changes
- Added new custom Origin/Remote pointing to my REPO 2
- Trying to push - but as REPO 2 - it complain as below

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes

Which make sense also as remote have some code already and looks like I am missing some steps or not doing it correctly, so how to effectively do this ? 
Please guide.

Comment: Did you try pulling the changes from the remote? You have to integrate those changes before you can push additional changes, unless you do the work on a different branch and merge it in.

Comment: Two seperate folders have two different projects from Repo 1 and Repo 2.

Comment: If i change origin of REPO1 to point to REPO2 and pull it will override my all local work right from REPO1 ?

Comment: Why it is marked -1 ? it is valid question with all required inputs.

Comment: No, it wouldn't overwrite your changes. It would update the local repository with the missing series of commits and create a merge commit for any changes. If there are conflicts, you'll have to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Sure let me give it a try and come back.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. That worked and it shows me many conflicts that is expected as i have to resolve manually. also showed me one error regarding unrelated history, which i solved with  git pull origin branchname --allow-unrelated-histories

Comment: Not sure why some one marked it downvote :( with no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the changes from the remote. That will update your local repo with all of the commits made since the fork diverged. At that point, any commits you made will be merged.

Additionally, you may have to perform conflict resolution to ensure your changes are properly merged with the changes to the remote.